# C: unordered floating-point comparison does not raise FE_INVALID

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, floating-point-exceptions

I've run into an issue with floating-point comparisons. When comparing a value with NaN using the `<` operator, I expect the `FE_INVALID` flag to be set. The `<` operator should raise the flag according to the C11 standard (and also according to IEEE-754):

> The `isless` macro determines whether its first argument is less than
>   its second argument. The value of `isless(x, y)` is always equal to
>   `(x) < (y)`; however, **unlike `(x) < (y)`**, `isless(x, y)` does not
>   **raise the "invalid" floating-point exception** when `x` and `y` are
>   **unordered**.

Here is an example program to reproduce my issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

int main()
{
    volatile float a = 12.0f;
    volatile float b = NAN;
    volatile int   c;

    feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);

    c = (a < b);

    if (fetestexcept(FE_INVALID))
        printf("FE_INVALID\n");
    else
        printf("Not invalid\n");

    return 0;
}
```

On my machine (Linux, `march=broadwell`) it returns "Not invalid".
I compiled it using GCC v7.2.0, using the `-std=c11` option (not using it didn't change anything in the result). The emitted x86 instruction is `UCOMISS` which is only raising exceptions for signalling NaNs - I would expect to see `COMISS` as that would raise the exception on all NaN comparisons, as NaNs are unordered no matter whether they're signalling or not.

Did I make a mistake in my code or forget some compiler option to make the behavior IEEE-compliant? Could it be a bug (or performance optimization) in the compiler to ignore the need to raise an exception here?

Comment: FWIW with MSVC the output is "FE_INVALID" and `c` is 0 although I commented out the pramga because it is not recognised.

Comment: Corner: Insure `feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);` returns zero.

Comment: Check `__STDC_IEC_559__`.  "An implementation that
defines _ _STDC_IEC_559_ _ shall conform to the specifications in this annex." (IEEE-compliant? )  If `__STDC_IEC_559__` is not defined, code is not specified to behave as desired.  Only mistake then is an incorrect expectation.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's strange, but at least it works for you :)
@chux just checked `feclearexcept`, it returns 0. Also very good point about IEEE-compliance. (Un)fortunately, `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined, so the issue lies somewhere else..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so I took the plunge and got the most recent GCC version (8.2) running.

The code behaves as expected when compiled under **GCC 8.2.0**, so I'll assume the problem was a compiler bug. I didn't try other versions in between 7.2.0 and 8.2 to see at which point it started working, but using 8.2 is good enough for me.